# inserting an related item to a table in SQL instead of making two db calls from c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

In my scenario, when the user replies to a post, a notification should be sent to the post owner. Currently, first I make a db call to add the reply record. Then, I check if reply is inserted successfully. If so, I create an instance of Notification object, I make another call to db to insert the notification record.

To decrease the db load, I thought about adding the notification record when I make the first call for adding the reply record. In Add Reply SQL stored procedure, I can also include the INSERT code for adding the notification record.

Is handling this directly in SQL a recommended approach? What is a good way of doing this without multiple db calls?

Comment: It seems work for a Stored Procedure or perhaps a trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Steve an sp or trigger would be best but regardless of how you do it it's still 2 calls as you are doing 2 inserts. If you do this from your application level you can do both queries by opening one connection but it's still 2 calls. If you really need to reduce this to one call I would rethink your application level and perhaps use the actual reply as the data that feeds the notification. So when checking for notifications you just check the reply table and have a field on there to indicate if it's an unread notification.

Comment: sounds very interesting. let me see if I get it correctly: instead of creating a new table for notifications, I should put a new field to Reply table, called IsRead, and generate the notifications on the fly in application based on the Reply table, is that right?

Comment: Yeah that's what I would do to reduce the number of calls

Answer (score 1):

Yes, handling that in the stored procedure is a perfectly fine approach.